# Reduce image collection to get daily sum from hourly precipitation GSMaP 12:00h pm to 11:00h am

Tags: google-earth-engine, precipitation, qgsmapcanvas

I am trying to adapt a script made available by colleagues from the GEE of the GSMaP image collection. The script obtains data (as a table) of the points of each image available in a given period and adds the hourly data per day. In my case, I want to compare this data (daily sum) with rain data that is collected from 12:00pm to 11:00am (Brazil). Therefore, you would need help for the script to add, for example, from 12:00pm 01/01/2019 to 11:00am 01/02/2019. Please find the script that needs to be improved below:

```
var p1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([69.15, 54.8331]),
    p2 = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Point([70.917, 54.433]),
    p3 = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Point([66.967, 54.367]);

// Collection of point
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([ee.Feature(p1),ee.Feature(p2), ee.Feature(p3)]))

// Start and End Dates
var inidate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,1,1)
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,3,1)

// Difference between start and end in days 
var difdate = enddate.difference(inidate, 'day')

// Import GSMaP data
var gsmap = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/reanalysis')
.filterDate(inidate, enddate)
.select('hourlyPrecipRateGC');

// Time lapse
var lapse = ee.List.sequence(0, difdate.subtract(1))
var inidate = ee.Date('2014-01-01')
var listdates = lapse.map(function(day){
  return inidate.advance(day, 'day')
})

// Iterate over the list of dates
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(listdates.iterate(function(day, ft) {
  // Cast
  ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ft)
  day = ee.Date(day)

  // Filter the collection in one day (24 images)
  var day_collection = gsmap.filterDate(day, day.advance(1, 'day'))

  // Get the sum of all 24 images into one Image
  var sum = ee.Image(day_collection.sum())

  // map over the ft to set a property over each feature
  var temp_ft = ft.map(function(feat){
    var geom = feat.geometry()
    var value = sum.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 30).get('hourlyPrecipRateGC')
    return feat.set(day.format('YYYY-MM-dd'), value)
  })

  // Return the FeatureCollection with the new properties set
  return temp_ft
}, pts))

print(newft)

// Export
Export.table.toDrive(newft,
"KZ_GSMaP_14-15",
"KZ_GSMaP_point data",
"KZ_GSMaP_14-15")
```

Comment: * the formation of the image of accumulated daily precipitation starts with the search for the 12: 00 pm image of the day and ends with the 11: 00 am image of the subsequent day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a list of start dates using the brazil GMT like this:

```
// Time lapse
var lapse = ee.List.sequence(0, difdate.subtract(1))
  // time zone Brazil (GMT-2, -3, -4 or -5)
                    // YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
var inidate = ee.Date('2014-01-01T12:00-03:00') 
var listdates = lapse.map(function(day){
          // start date 
  return inidate.advance(day, 'day');
})
print(listdates)
```

And then apply the same code (note that the end date is exclusive, thus adding one day (24hours) would be correct)

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e37e48f228fa19a462a6785ad6c59e60)

Comment: Dear @Kuik, you solved my problem.

Comment: My script is giving a problem in featurecollection, when I run the code below. I don't know what it might be. 

The code is available at the link below. If you can help me, thank you.

[link] (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ffelipe2cardoso%2Fscripts%3AGSMaP)